# SVAR residual calculation python has problem?

Tags: statsmodels

I am using statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.svar_model.SVAR function. I am not sure if the calculation for residuals ("resid" in the code) is correct because it seems that it does not take the contemporaneous terms into account.

Comment: Am I right that the residuals are forecast errors (obtained from the reduced form) not the residuals of SVAR model?

Answer (score 0):

Autoregression methods are based on least square ones and "resid" means Least Square method fitting residuals, not prediction errors.

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ARResults.resid.html

In addition, "residual" usually means estimation errors:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals